# Haskell RegEx Matching on UTF8 file

Tags: regex, haskell, encoding, pcre

I wrote this function

```hs
module PdfParser (parseOptions) where

import Text.Regex.PCRE
import Data.List.Split

parseOptions :: String -> [String]
parseOptions s = splitOn "\n" (s =~ regex :: String)
  where 
    regex = "(?<=OPTIONS\n)((.|\n)*?)(?=INTERIEUR|INTÉRIEUR|EQUIPEMENTS DE SERIE)"
```

And test

```hs
module PdfParserSpec (spec) where

import Test.Hspec
import Test.QuickCheck
import PdfParser(parseOptions)

spec :: Spec
spec =  do
  describe "PdfParser (parseOptions)" $ do
    it "return List of options" $ do
      referencialText <- readFile "test/assets/referential.txt"
      parseOptions referencialText `shouldBe` [
        "Peinture métallisée 550 €"
        ,"Jantes alliage 17\" Viva Stella [RDIF21] 300 €"
        ,"Chargeur sans fil 250 €"
        ,"Roue de secours tôle [RSEC01] 150 €"]
```

But when I read the text file, all my char éè etc.. are replace by \233f\233. Then my regex don't work.

Test result :

```
 test/PdfParserSpec.hs:12:7: 
  1) PdfParser, PdfParser (parseOptions), return List of options
       expected: ["Peinture m\233tallis\233e 550 \8364","Jantes alliage 17\" Viva Stella [RDIF21] 300 \8364","Chargeur sans fil 250 \8364","Roue de secours t\244le [RSEC01] 150 \8364"]
        but got: ["s alliage 17\" Viva Stella [RDIF21] 300 \8364","Chargeur sans fil 250 \8364","Roue de secours t\244le [RSEC01] 150 \8364","INT\201RIEUR","Sellerie Zen (Au lieu de Selleri"]
```

My regex work on my file -> https://regex101.com/r/HYBmMh/1

How can I fix that ?

Comment: These are *not* replaced with `\233`, etc. This is just how the string is *represented*. The double quotes for example are not part of the string either.

Comment: Never use `(.|\n)*?`, always use a dot with the DOTALL modifier, or `[\s\S]*?` / `[\w\W]*?`/ `[\d\D]*?` as workarounds.

Comment: When I replaced with [\s\S]*? I got compiler error "lexical error in string/character literal at character 's'"

Comment: @Antonin: you should use `[\\s\\S]*?` exactly for the same reason as why you escape characters like in the first comment.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks you :) But there is an offset in my match.
https://github.com/audreyt/regex-pcre-builtin/issues/3 That's why I think it don't work :(

Comment: FWIW if I use the `import regex` clause under Python 3.9.2, the regex as provided by Antonin works fine. It also works fine if `(.|\n)*?` gets replaced by `[\s\S]*?` or `[\\s\\S]*?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed hackage **regex-pcre-builtin** to **light-pcre**. And it works !

I haved to encode my strings into ut8 bytestring then add utf8 compile-time flag

```hs
module PdfParser (parseOptions) where

import Text.Regex.PCRE.Light(compile, utf8, match)
import Data.ByteString.UTF8(toString, fromString)
import Data.List.Split
import Data.String.Utils(strip)

parseOptions :: String -> Maybe [String]
parseOptions s = (splitOn "\n" . strip . toString . (!!0)) <$> (match regex (fromString s) [])
  where 
    regex = compile (fromString "(?<=OPTIONS\n)([\\s\\S]*?)(?=INTÉRIEUR)") [utf8]
```

Thank you for your comments :)